# Short story where a boy is inspired to become a scientist and invent time travel due to death of his brother

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

The story would most likely have been in one of the magazines in thew 50s or 60s. It starts out with the boy's brother dying in a sledding accident, and that inspires the kid to grow up to be a scientist and invent time travel. I don't remember the rest of the story.

I read the usual ones: Astounding, Galaxy, F&SF. I'm 90% sure it was a sledding accident, the problem is that *It's A Wonderful Life* had one in it, and I hope I'm not mixing them up. Something did go wrong with the time travel, something basic like only being able to travel forward, he never gets to go back to that day. His whole goal was to go back and prevent the accident. Some dim memory keeps insisting the brother's name was Manny, but I have no confidence in that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Larry Niven's [Wrong Way Street](http://apbsal.blogspot.com/2013/12/wrong-way-street-by-larry-niven.html?m=1) originally published on Galaxy in 1965 but reprinted in many other [places](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40766).

**It starts out with the boy's brother dying in a sledding accident, and that inspires the kid to grow up to be a scientist and invent time travel.**

> As a child, Mike Capoferri accidentally killed his brother, shaping
> him.  Doctor Stuart told him that time was a "one-way street."  After
> Mike moves to the moon, he proves the doctor wrong.
>
> The moons' new human resident discover alien artifacts on the
> moon--one a ship, inside a mysterious pyramid.  Mike fiddles with the
> pyramid by instinct and finds himself in another time

So the hero doesn't invent time travel, but his brother's death makes him interested in time travel.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I now remember how he immediately insisted that he wanted to travel back to save his brother. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah - he told the therapist (Doctor Stuart) that he wanted a time machine to prevent the accident.